# R: Sort a data frame based on the order of a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my example dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(c(123,456),each=5),col1=c(3,6,4,3,8,9,2,1,3,4),col2=c(7,8,5,4,6,8,7,5,8,3))

    id col1 col2
1  123    3    7
2  123    6    8
3  123    4    5
4  123    3    4
5  123    8    6
6  456    9    8
7  456    2    7
8  456    1    5
9  456    3    8
10 456    4    3

desiredOrder <- rep(c(456,123),each=5)
```

And I want to sort according to the order specified in a particular vector (desiredOrder), so that the output looks like this:

```
    id col1 col2
1  456    9    8
2  456    2    7
3  456    1    5
4  456    3    8
5 456    4    3
6  123    3    7
7  123    6    8
8  123    4    5
9  123    3    4
10  123    8    6
```

(so the rows where id=456 got moved up above the rows where id=123, but the original order of the rows are preserved)

I have tried:

```
df[match(df$id,desiredOrder),]
```

However the outcome is quite far from what I'm after:

```
     id col1 col2
6   456    9    8
6.1 456    9    8
6.2 456    9    8
6.3 456    9    8
6.4 456    9    8
1   123    3    7
1.1 123    3    7
1.2 123    3    7
1.3 123    3    7
1.4 123    3    7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can convert the 'id' column to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements in the `vector` and then do the `order`

```
df[order(factor(df$id, levels=unique(desiredOrder))),]
#    id col1 col2
#6  456    9    8
#7  456    2    7
#8  456    1    5
#9  456    3    8
#10 456    4    3
#1  123    3    7
#2  123    6    8
#3  123    4    5
#4  123    3    4
#5  123    8    6
```

Comment: Just for the sake of an easy example I've put the id column in ascending order and the solution has the id column in descending order... but in real life the id isn't in ascending order. I need the order of the ID column to be the order specified in the vector (desiredOrder). Sorry the question isn't very clear I'll fix it now

Comment: @HollowBastion  Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(id = desiredOrder) %>%
  distinct %>%
  left_join(df)
```

Comment: Similarly in base R - `merge(list(id=unique(desiredOrder)), df, sort=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use arrange() and desc() functions of dplyr library:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df, desc(id))

    id col1 col2
1  456    9    8
2  456    2    7
3  456    1    5
4  456    3    8
5  456    4    3
6  123    3    7
7  123    6    8
8  123    4    5
9  123    3    4
10 123    8    6
```